# What is RDD Block that is shown in the Executors tab page in Apache Spark

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, rdd

Please explain what is RDD Block that is shown in the Executors tab page in spark UI. I have highlighted it below.

**In my case i mostly always see RDD blocks as 2.**

Is it something related to parallelism ??? . As u can see that no.of Active cores is 4 but RDD blocks is mostly 2-3 in my case - Please can u explain ??

Also what should be the Ideal TASK execution time. I have read in a blog that a Task should run atleast for 100 ms.

https://umbertogriffo.gitbooks.io/apache-spark-best-practices-and-tuning/content/sparksqlshufflepartitions_draft.html

This is for minimum run time ..But what should be the Ideal task execution time so that we can decide whether to Decrease or  Increase the Partitions .??